# No scan result with wlan0 on Kali 2020.1

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, network-interface, iwlwifi

My Kali2020.1 came without any `wlan0`. During the installation, I recieve the indication that the firmwares microcodes`iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode` `iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode` should be added via an external drive.

I therefore have loaded the modules with the proposed tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@sagartripathi/ethical-hacking-fix-wlan0-not-showing-on-kali-linux-45a7cec04565).

```
# cd compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p
# make load


 Stoping bluetooth service..
Stopping bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Mar 16 12:18:04 hostname systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 16 12:18:04 hostname bluetoothd[7080]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Mar 16 12:18:04 hostname bluetoothd[7080]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Mar 16 12:18:04 hostname bluetoothd[7080]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Mar 16 12:18:25 hostname systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Mar 16 12:18:25 hostname bluetoothd[7080]: Terminating
Mar 16 12:18:25 hostname bluetoothd[7080]: Stopping SDP server
Mar 16 12:18:25 hostname bluetoothd[7080]: Exit
Mar 16 12:18:25 hostname systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Succeeded.
Mar 16 12:18:25 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Unloading ipw2200...
Unloading libertas_cs...
Unloading usb8xxx...
Unloading adm8211...
Unloading zd1211rw...
Unloading iwl3945...
Unloading ath...
Unloading p54pci...
Unloading p54usb...
Unloading rt2400pci...
Unloading rt2500pci...
Unloading rt61pci...
Unloading rt2500usb...
Unloading rt73usb...
Unloading rtl8187...
Unloading mwl8k...
Unloading mac80211_hwsim...
Unloading at76c50x_usb...
Unloading rndis_wlan...
Unloading mac80211...
Unloading cfg80211...
Unloading hidp...
Unloading rfcomm...
Unloading bnep...
Unloading btusb...
Loading ipw2100...
Loading ipw2200...
Loading libertas_cs...
Loading usb8xxx...
Loading p54pci...
Loading p54usb...
Loading adm8211...
Loading zd1211rw...
Loading rtl8180...
Loading rtl8187...
Loading p54pci...
Loading p54usb...
Loading iwl3945...
Loading iwlagn...
Loading ath...
Loading ar9170usb...
Loading rtl8180...
Loading rtl8187...
Loading rt2400pci...
Loading rt2500pci...
Loading rt61pci...
Loading rt2500usb...
Loading rt73usb...
Loading rndis_wlan...
Loading at76_usb...
Loading mwl8k...
Loading mac80211_hwsim...
Loading at76c50x_usb...
Loading bluetooth...
Loading btusb...
Loading l2cap...
Loading sco...
Loading hidp...
Loading rfcomm...
Loading bnep...
Starting bluetooth service..
Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-03-16 12:18:27 CET; 35ms ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7315 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9125)
     Memory: 980.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7315 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 16 12:18:27 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 16 12:18:27 hostname bluetoothd[7315]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Mar 16 12:18:27 hostname systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 16 12:18:27 hostname bluetoothd[7315]: Starting SDP server
Mar 16 12:18:27 hostname bluetoothd[7315]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

`wlan0` now appears in `ifconfig` output. There is however no scan result:

```
# iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     No scan results
```

**What should I do in order for wlan0 to have a non-empty scan ?**

---

```
# ifconfig

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet #########  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast #########
        inet6 #########  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 28:d2:44:22:c7:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 643806  bytes 884483621 (843.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 331  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57259  bytes 7261842 (6.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 422  bytes 59906 (58.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 422  bytes 59906 (58.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 72:66:36:a7:fe:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d6:83:19:6c:18:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
 # iwlist wlan0

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

---

```
 # lspci -v | grep Network -A 20  
        03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n)
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
        Memory at f1c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number a4-4e-31-ff-ff-5c-23-ec
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

---

`lsmod` output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QYrXxtQPwg/

Comment: What is the results of the `ifconfig` output?

Comment: @kemotep I have edited the post